# Fedora 20 memory.limit_in_bytes not working

Tags: memory, fedora, cgroups

Fedora 29 (kernel 3.15.10-201.fc20.x86_64)  This worked in F19.

I'm trying to use cgroups to limit memory usage for some apps that are prone to misbehaviour, and I'm encountering problems.  I'm testing with a small single-purpose program.

I have this in my `/etc/cgconfig.conf` file:

```
group memtest {
    memory {
        memory.limit_in_bytes = "209715200";
        memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = "104857600";
    }
}
```

and this in `/etc/cgrules.conf`:

```
*:memtest   memory      memtest/
```

The `memtest.c` file simply `malloc`'s 1GiB, sleeps for 30 seconds, and then frees the buffer and exits.

When the `memtest` program is running, its PID is properly listed in `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memtest/tasks`, showing that it's being classified correctly.  However, its memory use is **not** being limited.

Using `ulimit` the behaviour is as expected:

```
$ (ulimit -S -v 200000 ; ./memtest )
malloc failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

Here's the source of `memtest.c`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main() {
    char    *buf;
    size_t  bytes = (1 * 1<<30);

    errno = 0;
    buf = malloc(bytes);
    if (errno != 0) {
        int errno_copy = errno;
        perror("malloc failed");
        return errno_copy;
    }
    printf("%d bytes allocated (requested %d)\n",
           malloc_usable_size(buf),
           bytes);
    sleep(30);
    printf("Freeing..\n");
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the task getting properly classified, but not limited in its memory use?  What changed between F19 and F20?  (I only upgraded to F20 last week.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the only thing I can think of is that somewhere along the line processing (by the system) of the cgconfig.conf became more stringent. Rather than defining the limits as a quoted string, what happens if you remove the quotes. So something like:

```
group memtest {
    memory {
        memory.limit_in_bytes = 209715200;
        memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = 104857600;
    }
}
```

After contemplation I think memory.limit_in_bytes only limits the physical user memory but does allow for swap to be used. Is it possible all you need to do is set `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes` to be the same value as `memory.limit_in_bytes` so something like:

```
group memtest {
    memory {
        memory.limit_in_bytes = 209715200;
        memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = 209715200;
        memory.soft_limit_in_bytes = 104857600;
    }
}
```

memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes includes user memory AND swap. So if you want 0 swap space then one must set `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes` equal to `memory.limit_in_bytes`

When you do `ulimit -S -v 200000` that restricts virtual memory (swap, shared data, AND physical ram) to a specific amount so your application won't have enough space. However the normal system settings you had didn't limit swap space so it probably had ample room to use the maximum user memory + plus unused swap space.

Had you turned swap off (and not used ulimit) prior to doing your tests I would expect your program would have failed to allocate the memory it requested.

Comment: I don't think that's it; the controller's fields have the correct values:  `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memtest/memory.{soft_,}limit_in_bytes` => `104857600` and `209715200`.  (Confounded no-codeblock in comments.. *Or* preview..)

Comment: I have made an edit regarding `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes` to also ensure no swap space can be used beyond the user memory limit by making both the same.

Comment: I tried adding the `memsw` value a while ago, but it didn't make any difference.  Changing the `malloc()` to `calloc()` did, though -- *then* the limit came into play.  However, it went straight to the `oom_killer` rather than blowing out on the soft limit with `(12) Cannot allocate memory` as it does with the `ulimit` approach.